# How do I get back the "magnetic" vertical/horizontal green guides in MS Word 16 on macOS?

Tags: microsoft-word

I recently switched to macOS and MS Word 16. On Windows, I had vertical/horizontal bright green guides that would pop up when I move a text box/picture around to indicate where are the margins or where is the middle of the page. They would "attract" the object I was moving around. They were really convenient to properly place items.

Can I get them back? I've looked around but can't find anything, probably because I don't know how MS Office calls them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alignment options are on the Layout tab. Sorry to say, no pretty green lines. Look at the Grid Setting Options and that is where you can make it "Magnetic" with the Snap To control.

Grid options can also be accessed from Word > Preferences > View